# What are advantages of using Generators/Yields + co over Promises in node.js application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

It's been a long road to Async/Await in javascript. It gives us eloquent syntax for writing asynchronous code in synchronous style. Hopefully we will get it in near future. Now we can use Generators/Yields + co in node.js to emulate async/await behavior. I'd like to know advantages of this approach over using native Promises to achieve the same goal?

Comment: You can use `async/await` with Babel.

Comment: It's just a different style of writing code. Async/Await and co/yield use promises too. I prefer co/yield since I think it makes the code cleaner and it's easier to understand running top-to-bottom, but others may not share this opinion.

Comment: Both `async`/`await` and generators+`Co` do go **along** with promises, which are a part of their working. You cannot really compare them against each others.